# Listview control template. How to add an event to command?

Tags: wpf, listview

```
<ListView 
                    x:Name="ListViewPoducts"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ProductGroups}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProductGroup}"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    Background="{StaticResource NouvemLightBackgroundBrush}">

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Border  Background="Transparent" >
                                    <Button Name="button" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonTouchscreenMenu}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                       FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Static global:ApplicationSettings.TouchscreenMenuButtonFontSize}}"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                       TextAlignment="Center" 
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp">
                                                <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GroupSelectedCommand}" />
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    </Button>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="button"  Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NouvemSecondaryMainBrush}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleScrollBarTouchscreenNarrow}"/>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
```

Hello,

I'm trying to add a event to command trigger for buttons contained in a listview control template. We have an application running on a clients touchscreen which is overly sensitive to button presses. I want to handle a buttons PreviewMouseUp event to get around this (Currently when they press a button, it will also press whats underneath the button i.e. like pressing the button twice)

However, the command handler code doesn't get hit in my view model.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set `IsHitTestVisible` to "True" by the Button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView 
                    x:Name="ListViewPoducts"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ProductGroups}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProductGroup}"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    Background="{StaticResource NouvemLightBackgroundBrush}">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Border  Background="Transparent" >

                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp">
                                            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.HandeProductionProductGroupSelectionCommand, ElementName=ListViewPoducts}"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <Button Name="button" Style="{StaticResource StyleButtonTouchscreenMenu}" IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                       FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Static global:ApplicationSettings.TouchscreenMenuButtonFontSize}}"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                       TextAlignment="Center" 
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Button>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="button"  Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NouvemSecondaryMainBrush}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleScrollBarTouchscreenNarrow}"/>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
```

I figured it out. Just needed to bind my event to command to the root element data context.

Thanks